# Is the usage of "as" in this sentence valid?

Tags: prepositions

It is from this [webpage](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2009/11/25/whats_wrong_wit/):

> In response to my offhand remark that the kernel densities in the article by Chen and Rodden are “tacky” and would be much better **as** histograms, commenter Anne asks:...

It the usage of "as" here valid, should he mean "with"?

Comment: 1) It depends on context 2) You should give more context (the original, not just the link) 3) The link has a link which is broken, so you should do the work to make it easier for us to analyse. 4) It should be 'as' because a histogram and a kernel density are both types of graph and the suggestion is to replace one with the other ('as'), not to add an extra histogram ('with').

Comment: To an outsider, 'the kernel densities in the article by Chen and Rodden are “tacky” and would be much better as histograms' confuses data and the representation of data, and also raises the problem of what precisely is meant by 'tacky', especially in scare quotes.. If the data itself is shoddy (one sense given when one looks up _tacky_ in a reputable dictionary), the research itself is worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... be much better [presented] as histograms...."

We are often comfortable leaving words out for lots of reasons. I would not feel compelled to edit "as" in the original sentence, and I wouldn't replace it with "with."